# Getting a jquery slider banner to direct to another page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using a template that has a jquery slider.  I've changed the pics, words, etc.  I've also added the a href to direct the banners to other pages.  It doesn't work and I have absolutely no idea why.

This is the site - http://www.luckiedogfoundation.org.  It's the slider on the homepage.  If you hover over the banners on the left you can see they should redirect, but when you click on them - they don't.

Here is the HTML for them:

```
<ul class="pagination">
<li id="banner1"><a href="Help.html">Make<span>Donations</span></a></li>
<li id="banner2"><a href="Help.html">Be A<span>Volunteer</span></a></li>
<li id="banner3"><a href="tellothers.html">Tell<span>A Friend</span></a></li>
</ul>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  I've already spent 2 days trying to figure this out and I'm ready to rip my hair out.

I'm terrified it's somewhere in the javascript and since javascript looks like an alien language to me - I may be doomed.

Thanks.

Comment: What's the Javscript/JQuery?

Comment: It appears to be [this plugin](http://mydummysite.com.au/qnpx/documentation/JustSlider/) controlling the images and (possibly) messing up the link functionality. Also on that site is the [tms-0.3.js](http://mydummysite.com.au/qnpx/documentation/JustSlider/js/tms-0.3.js) that the OP is using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The plugin you're using doesn't appear to have very good documentation, but removing 'pagination' seems to do the trick. Change the following code at the bottom of your pages to remove pagination (thereby allowing links to direct user as expected):

```
$(window).load(function(){
    $('.slider')._TMS({
        preset:'zabor',
        easing:'easeOutQuad',
        duration:800,
        //pagination:true,
        banners:true,

...
...
```